# Google maps overlay clickable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Im new to javascript. In a map, when an overlay is clicked, I am trying to make it so that a function is called that has access to the clicked overlay.

Here is my code, not getting any errors in the console.

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="multi_overlays" style='width: 1000px; height: 600px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');

    handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'multi_overlays'}}, function(){

      var circles = handler.addCircles(
        [{ lat: 41.991873, lng: -70.652213, radius: 2000 }],
        { strokeColor: '#FF0001'}
      );

        var polylines = handler.addPolylines(
          [
          [
          ]
        ],
        { strokeColor: '#FF0000'}
      );


        var polygons = handler.addPolygons(
          [
            //ccb_nw
              [{lat:41.83,lng:-70.44},{lat:41.87,lng:-70.28},{lat:41.77,lng:-70.49},{lat:41.75,lng:-70.19}],
            //ccb_se
              [{lat: 41.984198, lng: -70.319776}, {lat: 41.970926, lng: -70.110349},{lat: 41.825776, lng: -70.164594},{lat: 41.803259, lng: -70.222959}],
            //ccb_sw
              [{lat: 41.887260, lng: -72.529131}, {lat: 41.920867, lng: -70.335363},{lat: 41.794781, lng: -70.283835},{lat: 41.783006, lng: -70.498755}],
          ],
              { strokeColor: '#FF0000'}
        );


      handler.bounds.extendWith(polylines);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(polygons);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(circles);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();  

      markers = handler.addMarkers([{"lat":42.30010009999999,"lng":-70.2994764,"infowindow":"Bass bite is picking up"},{"lat":41.6820897,"lng":-69.95976639999999,"infowindow":"Tuna non existent"},{"lat":42.0417525,"lng":-70.6722767,"infowindow":"good trip"},{"lat":42.072454,"lng":-70.206835,"infowindow":"On fire"}]);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();


    });
</script>
```

I tried using Google Maps addListener event to listen for clicks:

```
handler.addListener('click', function(event){
  alert('the map was clicked');
});
```

The above code does not work.  The overlays appear but nothing happens when they are clicked.  I think it might have something to do with panes:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapPanes

But every time I try to add a overlayMouseTarget it tells me the object doesn't exist.  I am very lost.  How do I make an overlay clickable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to make a listener using the variable you set for the marker/circle you are using.
This should help you:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(<variable>, 'click', function (event) {
      handleClick(event); // Your function here
});
```

I have a bigger example here:
https://snippetbox.xyz/9eb54a2a1f52dc1f5d41/

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is asking for a way to add a click listener onto a overlay.  are you saying to make a marker on top of an overlay and add the click to that?

Comment: @Philip7899 It can be used to do both. I did answer the question here though. It was just some code that I had that might help to understand it though.